# How to copy a file from the app bundle to another directory without System.UnauthorizedAccessException?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, app-bundle

I try to copy a file that is included in the app bundle as a resource to the temp folder on the iPhone. While this works on the Simulator, on the device I get an exception:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
>   "/private/var/mobile/Applications/B763C127-9882-4F76-8860-204AFEA8DD68/Client_iOS.app/testbundle.zip"
>   is denied.

The code I use is below It cannot open the source file.

```
using(var sourceStream = File.Open("./demobundle.zip", FileMode.Open))
{
    sourceStream.CopyTo(targetStream);
}
```

What is the correct way of copying a file into a destination stream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why is it that I always find the answers to my questions practically immediately after I asked here? :-)

One has to specify the file access mode. If it is set to `Read`, it'll work. The default seems to be some write mode and that is obviously not possible.

```
using(var sourceStream = File.Open("./demobundle.zip", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    sourceStream.CopyTo(targetStream);
}
```

Comment: [`File.Open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will return an `UnauthorizedAccessException` for read-only files if you don't explicitly add `FileAccess.Read`.

Comment: It's one of the reason why Gendarme has a rule that ask you to always specify the `FileMode` and `FileAccess`. The defaults are not always what the developers expect and often differs on the execution (customer or device in this case) environment.